# Saving a model containing a FileField in Django

Tags: django, django-models

I have the below model;

```
class AudioFile(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='')
    audio_file = models.FileField()
    uploader = models.ForeignKey(User, default='')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

The below form;

```
class AudioFileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = AudioFile
        fields = ['name', 'audio_file']

    def clean_audio_file(self):
        audio = self.cleaned_data.get('audio_file',False)
        if audio:
            if audio._size > 5*1024*1024:
                raise ValidationError("File too large ( > 5mb )")
            if os.path.splitext(audio.name)[1] != ".mp3":
                raise ValidationError("We only support mp3!")
            return audio
        else:
            raise validationError("Couldn't read uploaded file")
```

As you can see there's some custom validations

Then I have the below html with the `AudioFileForm` passed as `form`;

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>

<body>
  <form method="post" action="{% url 'actual_upload_audio' %}">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form }}
    <input type="submit" value="Upload"/>
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Now I know how to save the object had it not been containing a FileField. I would do something like this;

```
form = AudioFileForm(request.POST)
if form.is_valid():
    name = form.cleaned_data['name']
    //Say it contained another field, foo
    foo = form.cleaned_data['foo'] 
    uploader = request.user //view requires login
    audio_file = Audio_File.objects.create(name=name,
                                           foo=foo,
                                           uploader=uploader)
    audio_file.save()
    return HttpResponse("Success!")
```

But there being a FileField in question I donno how to handle this. I read Django's documentation but don't really get it. A much easier elaborate explanation would be lovely.

For a start I have `MEDIA_ROOT = '/home/afzalsh/works/openradio/audio_files/'` in my `settings.py`

**Update**

Thanks to @Rohan I now have `<form method="post" action="{% url 'actual_upload_audio' %}" enctype="multipart/form-data">` instead of `<form method="post" action="{% url 'actual_upload_audio' %}">`

Also have the below view thanks to @dzejdzej;

```
form = AudioFileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.cleaned_data['uploader'] = request.user
        form.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('home_audio',kwargs={'pk':audio_file.pk}))
    else:
        return HttpResponse("Form Invalid!")
```

But `Form Invalid!` :/

Comment: Check why the form is invalid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using ModelForm, why not let Django handle saving the whole model?

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect

form = AudioFileForm(request.POST)
if form.is_valid():
    form.cleaned_data['uploader'] = request.user //view requires login
    form.save()
    return redirect(success_url)
```

If you're using Django >=1.7, upload_to field is no longer required. However, I consider it a good practice.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.FileField.upload_to

Also redirect user after successful POST to avoid issues with csrf.

Comment: print 'form.errors' and 'form.non_field_errors' to see what is going on
even better use python debugger:
'import pdb; pdb.set_trace() # insert before checkich form.is_valid()'

Comment: The problem was with my custom checks. Will figure that out later. But now I get `IntegrityError at /uploadaudio NOT NULL constraint failed: stationrunner_audiofile.uploader_id`

Comment: @Rohan please see the comment above

Answer (score 3):

Your form should have `enctype="multipart/form-data"` attribute so that it submits files.

```
<form method="post" action="{% url 'actual_upload_audio' %}"
       enctype="multipart/form-data" >
   ...
 </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

you should mention the upload_to attribute as :  audio_file = models.FileField(upload_to='uploads')

here 'uploads' is the name of the directory you would like to upload your files to.

Answer (score 0):

As `Rohan` seaid, you must defile your form in template like this.

```
<form method="post" action="{% url 'actual_upload_audio' %}"
       enctype="multipart/form-data" >
   ...
</form>
```

This allows you to send files with request to `view`. Now in view you must have something like this:

```
def my_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        my_form = MyForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if my_form.is_valid():
            my_form.save()
```

You can initial your form FileField and ImageField with **`request.FILES`**